# Android observe repository with flow and Result sealed dataclass

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm having trouble how to design the architecture of my Android App. I'm using the repository pattern, however, how can I observe a Room entity when the return type is a Dataclass with Success/Failure within a Flow and using a uiState Dataclass. Let me elaborate more with an image:

[image: Overall diagram]

1. In my viewmodel, I have the repository injected with Hilt. So I can call `_myRepo.getData()`.
2. The repository executes a network call (retrofit) and awaits the result.
3. The server returns a JSON with the data requested.
4. With a serializer, I convert the JSON to a list of DTOs. These DTO's are mapped to Entities and inserted in the Room Database.

Now comes the confusing part.

If my **ResultType** dataclass is:

```
sealed class ResultType<T> (val data : T? = null, val message : String? = null) {
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : ResultType<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String?, data: T? = null) : ResultType<T>(data, message)
    class Loading<T>(val isLoading: Boolean = true) : ResultType<T>(null)
}
```

In my **repository**, the function `getData()` looks like:

```
suspend fun getData() : Flow<ResultType<List<UserDataClass>>> = flow {
    try {
      emit(ResultType.Loading(true))
      val mylist = _api.getUsers(mapparameters).map { it.toUserEntity() }
      _db.userDao.delete()
      _db.userDao.insertAll(mylist)
      emit(ResultType.Success(_db.userDao.getAll().map { it.toUserDataClass() }))
    } catch (ex: HttpException) {
      emit(ResultType.Error(ex.localizedMessage))
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
      emit(ResultType.Error(ex.localizedMessage))
    }
}
```

So, in my **viewmodel**, I'm collecting the flow like this:

```
private fun getUsers() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _repository.getData(username, password).collect { result ->
            when (result) {
                is ResultType.Loading -> {
                    _uiState.update { prev ->
                        prev.copy(isLoading = true)
                    }
                }
                is ResultType.Success -> {
                    result.data?.let {
                        _myList = it.toMutableList()
                        _uiState.update { prev ->
                            prev.copy(
                            users = _myList,
                            isLoading = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, for the UI, the uiState is:

```
data class UsersState(
    val users : List<UserDataClass> = emptyList(),
    val isLoading : Boolean = true
)
```

This is where I'm currently stuck. Because I need to observe for any change in the Room database for those entities

Currently using MVVM for this project.
Let me know if you require more info

Comment: What is expected result and what is actual? In my current understanding, you want to observe the data continuously, in other words, you want to implement some kind of update listener which will automatically fetch new data from server?

Comment: Hi, I only want to observe the data once is inserted into Room. The fetch is made only once at startup. So, in the image, only observing from step "5" onwards

Comment: I proposed a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flow directly for your Room DAO objects. Don't actually know, how your data classes look like, but will assume:

```
@Dao
abstract class UsersDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
    abstract fun getUsers(): Flow<List<UserDataClass>>
}
```

Now, every update of the table will emit the new object in the flow. So, in your domain/presentation layer you should simply subscribe to the flow from your DAO.

At first, you need to provide access to dao from your repository

```
suspend fun getData(): Flow<<List<UserDataClass>> {
    try {
        val mylist = _api.getUsers(mapparameters).map { it.toUserEntity() }
        _db.userDao.delete()
        _db.userDao.insertAll(mylist) 
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // I let you implement catch blocks yourself, 
        // you probably don't want to emit an error if you want 
        // observe only actual updates of the table, not the errors
    }
    return _db.userDao.getUsers() // here you return your flow!
}
```

Then, in the presentation layer you can do:

```
private fun getUsers() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        _repository.getData().collect { usersList ->
            // your update logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after a few adjustments I get it to work. The idea you gave me was right.

Comment: What if we are using Retrofit and Room and want to use a Repository to fetch data from server if the data is not available in the local database, as i understand we can't make a direct flow from online server, so i create a function in repository to handle this logic to create a network request.

my questions is should i emit a new flow directly from repository to viewmodel, or do i have to pass the data to viewmodel and then emit a new flew from viewmodel to the view layer ?

Comment: @amir you usually want to provide the flow from your data  or domain layer

Comment: @Steyrix thanks, so i think its for the best to pass the data provided from room directly to vm through Repository since its already a flow, and if the data is provided from retrofit i just create a new flow and expose it to the vm. is this a right approach ?

Comment: @amir yes, it is. You can use https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow as an example